# What does "Tprint" mean in LTspice?

Tags: ltspice

**Specifically, the "Tprint" I am asking about is the one shown below, in the syntax explanation part, I tried finding out the function of this parameter by changing its value, but from my graph I didn't spot any change for telling.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I've read (but I really don't know for sure) that it's *"the time interval used for the printing of results of the transient analysis."*

Comment: Hi jonk, could you please tell me where you find this piece of information?

Comment: Look at page 5-25 [here](http://web.engr.uky.edu/~elias/tutorials/Eldo/eldo_ur.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, check the manual. In this case, under `LTspice > Dot Commands > .TRAN`:

> `Syntax: .TRAN <Tstep> <Tstop> [Tstart [dTmax]] [modifiers]`
>           `.TRAN <Tstop> [modifiers]`
>
> The first form is the traditional .tran SPICE command. Tstep is the plotting increment for the waveforms but is also used as an initial step-size guess. LTspice uses waveform compression, so this parameter is of little value and can be omitted or set to zero.

So it's mostly there for compatibility, since with or without waveform compression, the timestep is automatically chosen by the engine and the display of the waveform is done, also, automatically.

Comment: So what does Tprint indicate, I still don't really see it from your answer, could you elaborate? Do you mean that Tprint indicates the max interval between the printed dots on the plot while Tstep indicates the max interval between analyzed points?

Comment: @XuanhanZhu Looking at the syntax, `Tstep` and `Tprint` are the same (they are in the same position). Which means they represented the periodicity of the plotted points (remember that "plotted" literally comes from 40+ years ago when they used dot printers). And, as the quote shows, it was also used as a hint for the initial timestep. The reason you don't see any difference is because, as I said, it's there mostly for compatibility (running older schematics that already have a `.TRAN` card), and because today's engines have their own display routines and better timestep guessing.