# How to measure phase accurately using LTSpice?

Tags: ltspice, phase

I am trying, and failing, to measure phase in LTSpice.  I've used [the suggestion here](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/phase-measurement-in-lt-spice/)

```
.tran 0.00001 0.5
.meas TRAN time_1 TRIG V(N001)=0 RISE=1 TD=0.4 TARG V(N001)=0 RISE=2 TD=0.4
.meas TRAN time_2 TRIG V(N001)=0 RISE=1 TD=0.4 TARG V(N002)=0 RISE=1 TD=0.4
.meas phase param 360*time_2/time_1
```

but the result isn't very accurate, even for the simple RC filter in the picture below.

[image: LTSpice RC filter]

How *should* I be doing it?

Note that the actual phase I need to measure is in a slightly more complex circuit, but I've reduced it to a simple circuit that seems to have the same problem.

Comment: You won't get an accurate phase angle on the first cycle but it will get better as more cycles pass. You need to measure it when the system has settled down.

Comment: You might pref a better web-tool with lots of features http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$+0+0.000005+5+50+5+50%0A%25+4+1183.069613694428%0Ac+272+160+272+80+0+0.000009999999999999999+0%0Ar+192+80+272+80+0+1000%0AO+272+80+384+80+0%0Ag+272+160+272+192+0%0A170+192+80+160+80+3+20+1000+5+0.1%0Ao+4+16+0+34+5+0.00009765625+0+-1+in%0Ao+2+16+0+34+2.5+0.00009765625+1+-1+out%0A

Comment: @Andyaka Understood. That's what the time delay `TD=0.4` was supposed to do: get away from the start-up transients.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Sure! That's a great tool. But tangential: I need to solve my problem in LTSpice.

Comment: To make an acurate plot of the phase-over-frequency of such a simple filter I would not use the TRAN simulation, instead I would use the AC simulation. Then there are direct functions to make a (Bode) plot with the phase.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Yes... except I just want to measure the phase at a single frequency (500Hz here).  I thought that it might be simpler than a Bode plot over a frequency range... but it might not be possible.

Comment: You might be able to do an AC analysis at a single frequency, other (more professional) simulators can do this, LTSpice probably as well (I haven't tried that myself). Also, what prevents you to do an AC frequency sweep and only extracting the value at 500 Hz?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thank-you! See my answer. I eventually managed to get AC analysis to work with just three frequency points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The measurements should be fine, there is no one way to rule them all. You can use:

```
.meas t1 when v(1)=0 rise=1 td=0.4
.meas t2 when v(2)=0 rise=1 td=0.4
.meas phase param 360*(t2-t1)*500
```

just as well and it will give you what you want. It is assumed you are in the steady-state (the reason for adding `td`).

The problem is that you are using `.tran 10u 0.5` probably thinking that you are imposing a timestep, but that's not what it does. It [can be misleading](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/559526/95619), I agree. For an imposed timestep, you have to use:

```
.tran 0 0.5 0 10u
```

This, by itself, will help, but not much. By default, LTspice uses a waveform compression algorithm which limits the number of plotted points to 1024. For your case, `0.5/10u = 50k` points, which will be reduced, so to disable waveform compression, either alter the option in `Control Panel > Compression > Window size(No. of Points)` (the setting is *not* remembered during sessions), or add:

```
.opt plotwinsize=0
```

to the schematic. This is the preferred way, since it is remembered for any schematic that uses the option (and can be easily toggled between a SPICE directive, and a comment). The downside is that, with waveform compression off, the `.raw` file will grow and grow. One cure for that is to use the `.save` command.

Another thing that you can do to increase the accuracy is to use:

```
.opt numdgt=7 measdgt=13
```

Any number greater than `6` for `numdgt` enables `double` precision data points, while `measdgt` sets the number of digits for the `.meas`.

---

An `.AC` analysis is recommended for frequency domain measurements (as mentioned by [Bimpelrekkie](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/560876/how-to-measure-phase-accurately-using-ltspice/560881?noredirect=1#comment1463462_560876)), if possible (there are times when it's not). If it is possible, using `.ac list 500` will work fir this case. One thing to remember is that the number of `.AC` points is limited to 65536.

For those cases when it's not possible, regarding imposing an even smaller timestep, there is a workaround. If your circuit has a long settling time, imposing a very small timestep will mean possible hours of simulation and many GB of storage. There may be a trick  to avoid that: don't set a timestep, instead set up a `PULSE()` source with a delay `>=` settling time, and with a period `<=` the smallest desired timestep. This way, the simulation will fly during the transient, and will crawl during the steady-state.

For example, given the circuit in your picture, the 1% settling time should be after some 46 ms, so set up a source with `PULSE 0 1 50m 1u 1u 1u 4u`. This will impose a 1 µs timestep since the timepoints for the source are known, which means the solver will have to reduce the timestep to accomodate these.

The advantage is that it can also be turned on or off:

- If it only has to be turned off, then specifying the number of periods will do, but be careful with this: since the timepoints need to be known, that means there will be a delay before the simulation starts caused by calculating these timepoints. This only happens if the number is large (i.e. many timepoints to calculate). If the number of periods is not specified, the engine knows it only needs a simple repeating pattern of a few timepoints.
- If it needs to be turned on and off, then use the keyword `trigger`: `PULSE 0 1 50m 1u 1u 1u 4u trigger V(x)>0.3`, where `V(x)` is some controlling voltage. It's pretty self-explanatory, but for the sake of future readers, if `V(x)` is from another source, e.g. `SIN 0 1 10`, then the `PULSE()` source will be turned on everytime `V(x)>0.3, and off otherwise.

Comment: Great! Thank-you for your insights.  I've tried it out, and it works a little better but I still only get a one or two significant figure match with my analytical solution.  I'll leave it a day or two, but will give you the tick! :-)

Comment: @PeterK. You may need to make an even smaller timestep if you need extra accuracy, or maybe you're not really into steady-state, or maybe you need to take several measurements and make an average, but it sounds like what you're really after is an `.AC` analysis. I see in the comments this is mentioned. If only one single frequency is of interest, then use the command `.ac list 500`.

Comment: I've updated my answer, maybe it helps some more.

Comment: Bingo!  AC analysis worked! :-) Thank-you (and @Bimpelrekkie) for the suggestion. I'll write up my solution as a separate answer. Have a check mark! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As `Bimpelrekkie` suggested in the comments, and `a concerned citizen` mentioned in their answer, I eventually got accurate results using `.ac` analysis.

I eventually used:

```
.ac list 499 500 501
```

rather than a single frequency... because I couldn't get the cursor function in LTSpice to work with a single frequency.  However, adding the extra two (one extra might have been sufficient) allowed a non-zero value to be displayed in the cursor window.

[image: LTSpice screenshot]

And this version is accurate down to as many significant figures as I wanted.

For those interested, this is a video of [the actual circuit I was interested in solving.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZa9dUjbQZo)

Comment: Glad to hear. But if all you need is one frequency, only, then you don't need more than one number in the list: `.ac list 500` will do. For a single point measuring you won't see any plots (unless there's a `.step` involved), instead you'll get a popup with measurements. So be sure you label your nodes accordingly. +1 for entrepreneurial spirit (I hope I didn't butcher the word too much).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thanks for your kind words!  I can't figure out how to get the popup with measurements. If I use `.ac list 500` and label the top of `C1` as `Vout`, I can't see where I get one.  And when I add a cursor to the one-frequency plot, it just sits on (0,0), not on the actual plot (which shows as a horizontal line).

Comment: You should be getting [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3CTe.png). Maybe popup was the wrong choice of words? That text window pops up, instead of the waveform window. And if you need differential measuring, just add a VCVS (E source), or a behavioural source for more complicated expressions. In `.AC`, not all fomulas will work. Maybe in the Mac version there's a different behaviour? If you use a single frequency, does the waveform window pop up? That would be strange.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Yes, I just tried the same circuit on a Windows installation and it does pop that window up.  The MacOS behaviour is different!  Thank-you, again. I'll have to see how I can get that window on the mac.